# Deploying EAR on WAS 8.0

Tags: deployment, websphere, ear

I am trying to deploy my EAR application which contains a RAR, and couple of JAR modules. The application is working fine on WAS 7.0 but as soon as I start deploying it on WAS 8 I get following exception in FFDC logs;

```
[19/10/11 11:45:40:454 BST]     FFDC Exception:com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkForXmiFiles ProbeId:1322 Reporter:java.lang.Class@b88a90
com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: ADMA0208E: The Enterprise Archive (EAR) contains an unsupported xmi format bindings or extensions file.
at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkForXmiFiles(AppInstallHelper.java:1321)
at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkForEE5Restrictions(AppInstallHelper.java:511)
at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkForEE5Restrictions(AppInstallHelper.java:476)
at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getAppDeploymentInfo(AppInstallHelper.java:562)
at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.readArchive(AppManagementFactory.java:129)
at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.readArchive(AppManagementFactory.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.console.appmanagement.action.GatherTaskData.<init>(GatherTaskData.java:128)
at com.ibm.ws.console.appmanagement.controller.DefaultBindingsController.perform(DefaultBindingsController.java:137)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1147)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:722)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:449)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:92)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:932)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:499)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:320)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:919)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1016)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3639)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:950)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1659)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1648)

CapturedDataElements begin
arg0:null
arg1:null
CapturedDataElements end
```

Following are the contents of **application.xml** and **ibm-application-bnd.xmi** under 'xyzee.ear/META-INF';

**application.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <application id="tocfeeEAR" version="5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd">
<display-name>XYZ-EE_EAR</display-name>
<module>
  <connector>abcplugin-ra.rar</connector>
</module>
<module>
  <ejb>abclistener-ejb.jar</ejb>
</module>
<module>
  <ejb>abcmessage-ejb.jar</ejb>
</module>
<module>
  <ejb>delivery-ejb.jar</ejb>
</module>
<library-directory>lib</library-directory>  
</application>
```

**ibm-application-bnd.xmi**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.applicationbnd:ApplicationBinding xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.applicationbnd="applicationbnd.xmi" xmi:id="ApplicationBinding_1245927891310">
<authorizationTable xmi:id="AuthorizationTable_1245927891310"/>
<application href="META-INF/application.xml#abceeEAR"/>
</com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.applicationbnd:ApplicationBinding>
```

Your help and comments will be appreciated.

Thanks,

--

SJunejo

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you built the IBM-specific .xmi files, but it seems WebSphere 8 expects something different in at least one of them than WebSphere 7 did. (For instance, see [this problem report](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg1PM39082) for that same `ADMA0208E` error code.)

You can either rebuild the EAR with WebSphere 8 as the target (like if you used RAD or RSA; they ought to correct the files when you switch to a WebSphere 8 target), learn exactly what WebSphere 8 expects and manually build the files, or remove the .xmi files from the EAR and manually map everything at deploy time.

(I'm assuming the latter still works. It's the approach we use on WebSphere 6.1 since we build server-independent WARs and EARs. The .xmi files perform WebSphere-specific bindings that you can instead perform yourself in the admin console.)

Comment: You are correct. However it should be also enough to just delete *.xmi files from inside of the EAR. WAS will regenerate those when deploying.

Comment: I removed the ibm-application-bnd.xmi file from abcee.ear/META-INF folder and it worked.

Thanks guys for you help.

-- 

SJunejo